# MATLAB - function integral with few arguments

Tags: function, matlab, arguments, integral

I wanted to ask how I can compute the following integral in MATLAB.

```
integral( PN(x,m,s), x(-Inf,Inf) , m>0 , s>0.
```

I have created a function file, `pn`, which is:

```
function PN = pn(x,m,s)
    PN = exp(-(x-m).^2 ./ (2*s.^2)) ./ sqrt(2*pi*s.^2);
end
```

and a script `begin.m`:

```
%ezplot(@(x)pn(x,0,1),[-3,3])  --> This is OK!
quad(pn(x,m,s),x,-Inf,Inf)     --> I can't manipulate this, I tried several ways.
```

The answer to the integral must be "1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`quad` and other integration routines expect a [function handle](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-38133.html) in its first slot. Also, this function must except vector input and return vector output.  To fix your problem, try this instead,

```
m=0;
s=1;
F = @(x) pn(x,m,s);  % a function handle
quadgk(F,-inf,inf)   % quadgk excepts -inf to inf as limits
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks!This works fine!But we are taking m=0 and s=1 .I want m>0 and s>0.Is this the same?

Comment: yup,  do a change of variables z = (x - m)/(sqrt(2) s) under the integral to reduce it to the case where m=0, s=1.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend breaking it into the sum of two integrals: one from -Inf to zero, and another from zero to +Inf.